I need to generate QR code for some data, I don't want to use System.Drawing.Common . Any other suiatble way for generating QR code using C#
With System.Drawing.Common the type initializer for Gdip threw an exception.
Creating an API which should send a QR code (base64 encoded string) as a response. I tried using ZXing and System.Drawing.common libraries to generate QR code and then return it in byte[] so that can be converted in base64 string to send as a response in .net API.

Any reason why you are not interested to get that exception fixed but to opt for a completely differentt approach? Is my assumption about your goal here correct in the first place?

The very first reason is System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows. My Api is hosted in ubuntu server. Second reason is that I am using .net 8 with which system.Drawing.common is having some issues. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only

Specifically for QR barcodes you could use the QRCoder Nuget -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/QRCoder/
It doesn't need external dependencies and you can get your base64 directly from the result.
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
var qrString = $"QR Code string - for other types like urls check the readme in the nuget";
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(qrString, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
PngByteQRCode qrCode = new PngByteQRCode(qrCodeData);
byte[] qrCodeAsPngByteArr = qrCode.GetGraphic(5); // --> also read the readme
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(qrCodeAsPngByteArr, 0, qrCodeAsPngByteArr.Length);

This is the direct (png) output you can use like (as example)
var base64Png = $"<img src='data:image/png;base64,{base64String}' />";

As an off-hand remark, I'd suggest stop using System.Drawing.Common in general. The System.Drawing namespace has some serious issues when moving towards .NET 6+ and some other issues regarding .NET 5 (or lower). For more information read the "remarks" block issued by MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=net-8.0 (the "red" section should give enough information).
If you'd like to use drawing/imaging etc take a look at other nugets like https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.ImageSharp/ (but there are others)

"I'd suggest stop using System.Drawing.Common in general" - why? (Neutral on that, just thinking a good answer containing this remark should also give reasons for that suggestion)

You got a point there - I will add the explanation

Just one more remark, there - When opting for SixLabors: mind their licensing. (The reason one of our projects is migrating away from it)
